# Admin on rest - implementing aor-realtime

Tags: admin-on-rest

I'm having a real hard time understanding how to implement `aor-realtime` (trying to use it with firebase; reads only, no write).

The first place I get stuck: This library generates a saga, right? How do I connect that with a restClient/resource? I have a few custom sagas that alert me on errors, but there is a main restClient/resource backing those. Those sagas just handles some side-effects. In this case, I just don't understand what the role of the client is, and how it interacts with the generated saga (or visa-versa)

The other question is with persistence: Updates stream in and the initial set of records is not loaded in one go. Should I be calling `observer.next()` with each update? or cache the updated records and call `next()` with the entire collection to-date.

Here's my current attempt at doing the later, but I'm still lost with how to connect it to my Admin/Resource.

```
import realtimeSaga from 'aor-realtime';
import { client, getToken } from '../firebase';
import { union } from 'lodash'

let cachedToken 
const observeRequest = path => (type, resource, params) => {
    // Filtering so that only chats are updated in real time
    if (resource !== 'chat') return;

    let results = {}
    let ids = []

    return {
        subscribe(observer) {
            let databaseRef = client.database().ref(path).orderByChild('at')

            let events = [ 'child_added', 'child_changed' ]

            events.forEach(e => {
                databaseRef.on(e, ({ key, val }) => {
                    results[key] = val()
                    ids = union([ key ], ids)
                    observer.next(ids.map(id => results[id]))
                })  
            })          
            const subscription = {
                unsubscribe() {
                    // Clean up after ourselves
                    databaseRef.off()
                    results = {}
                    ids = []
                    // Notify the saga that we cleaned up everything
                    observer.complete();
                }
            };

            return subscription;
        },
    };
};

export default path => realtimeSaga(observeRequest(path));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I connect that with a restClient/resource?

Just add the created saga to the [custom sagas](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Admin.html#customsagas) of your `Admin` component.

About the restClient, if you need it in your observer, then pass it the function which return your observer as you did with `path`. That's actually how it's done in the [readme](https://github.com/marmelab/aor-realtime#usage).

> Should I be calling observer.next() with each update? or cache the updated records and call next() with the entire collection to-date.

It depends on the `type` parameter which is one of the admin-on-rest fetch types:

- `CRUD_GET_LIST`: you should return the entire collection, updated
- `CRUD_GET_ONE`: you should return the resource specified in params (which should contains its id)

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Gildas. I'm still a bit confused. Let me try to explain how I understand it now, and maybe you can tell me where I'm wrong. The generated saga listens for CRUD_GET_LIST and CRUD_GET_ONE events (optionally limited to a single resource). When receiving those events, it should use the params to start/update the realtime query. On new events, we call `observer.next()` (i assume this updates the store). I still don't understand how AOR knows which resource-name these events belong to, and then how do I add a <Resource/> tag for that resource in the <Admin/>. thanks again!

Comment: aor-realtime knows which resource because you returned an observer for the specific parameters you received (type, resource, params). It then trigger the related redux actions from aor using those parameters. I'm not sure I understand your second question about Resource though. Just declare it as you usually do with other resources ?

Comment: I get the first part now! For my second question: if the resource collection is being managed by the saga, what's my restClient supposed to do when it gets a request for that resource? I probably should have clarified in the beginning, I'm mixing this firebase-backed resource with other rest-api backed resources

Comment: I'll assume the resources managed by the firebase backend are also managed by your restClient for edition etc. ?

Comment: No, the firebase resources are read-only. I dont edit them through AOR. The other resources that i have are managed by my restClient for CRUD operations

Comment: Are they displayed using aor components ?

Comment: To clarify, if those resources are not managed at all by AOR, you don't need aor-realtime.

Comment: sorry for the late reply, got called off to work on something else. I'm back on this now and will post the solution i came up with, thanks to your help!

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution I came up with, with guidance by @gildas:

```
import realtimeSaga from "aor-realtime";
import { client } from "../../../clients/firebase";
import { union } from "lodash";
const observeRequest = path => {      
  return (type, resource, params) => {
    // Filtering so that only chats are updated in real time
    if (resource !== "chats") return;

    let results = {}
    let ids = []

    const updateItem = res => {
      results[res.key] = { ...res.val(), id: res.key }
      ids = Object.keys(results).sort((a, b) => results[b].at - results[a].at)
    }

    return {
      subscribe(observer) {
        const { page, perPage } = params.pagination
        const offset = perPage * (page - 1)

        const databaseRef = client
            .database()
            .ref(path)
            .orderByChild("at")
            .limitToLast(offset + perPage)

        const notify = () => observer.next({ data: ids.slice(offset, offset + perPage).map(e => results[e]), total: ids.length + 1 })

        databaseRef.once('value', snapshot => {
          snapshot.forEach(updateItem)
          notify()
        })

        databaseRef.on('child_changed', res => {
          updateItem(res)
          notify()    
        })


        const subscription = {
          unsubscribe() {
            // Clean up after ourselves
            databaseRef.off();
            // Notify the saga that we cleaned up everything
            observer.complete();
          }
        };

        return subscription;
      }
    };
  }
};

export default path => realtimeSaga(observeRequest(path));
```